# How to set upload file size in htaccess for uploading larger files ?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, php

I have a upload script which allows uploads up to 2 GB. My apache2 server allowed only 8MB of post_max_size. Is there any solution to define such properties from the php.ini in the htaccess. The reason why i want it to get it worked like that? I just want to use such big post_max_size only for my application not for the whole apache2 server.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds your'e mixing up things. "from the php.ini in the htaccess" - these are two different files.

Comment: You need to check if PHP is running as an Apache module; if so, [follow these instructions](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Comment: @jtheman - Depending on server config, you can put php.ini settings into .htaccess files.  The question is valid.

Comment: Ok (-: Valid question however probably not new.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `upload_max_filesize` property to whatever value you want within either php.ini, .htaccess, or even httpd.conf. If you are using PHP 5.3 above, you can also set this property in user.ini

Comment: You **cannot** use ini_set to set the upload_max_filesize property.

Comment: It is available in the appendix of the ini_set function. http://in2.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: The same appendix says that this setting is changeable `PHP_INI_PERDIR`... `ini_set` is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in htaccess files:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

or you can create php.ini file in root folder of your project put these two lines

```
upload_max_filesize=100M
post_max_size=100M
```

Comment: so create a file named by php.ini in root folder of your project and paste upload_max_filesize=100M
post_max_size=100M it should work.